# Changing a Mongodb Parameter Value Onclick

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, ejs

I want to make a report button for posts in my website, in my post model I have: reported: , with the default value of false, i want that if someone is clicking on the button the value will change to true.

My ejs on the html page:

```html
<% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>
        <% if(post.uploadedBy == Tuser){ %>
            <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4 class="display-4" style="text-transform: capitalize;"><%= post.title %></h4>
                    <h5><%= post.uploadedBy %></h5>
                    <p class="lead"><%= post.text %></p>
                    <a href="#" onclick="reported(<%= post %>)">Report Post</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% } %>
    <% }) %>
```

My GET for the page in the app.js file:

```js
//get someone else's blog
router.get('/othersblog/:username',(req,res) => {
    Post.find({},(err,posts) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{           
            res.render('othersblog',{
                headline: "Website | User Blog",
                title: "Blog",
                Tuser: req.params.username,
                posts: posts,
            });
        }
    })
});
```

If you know how to do it please help me. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope that it helps you, or give you an idea how to achieve your goal.

Comment: thank you so much it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can to do is to create a get route for each one `post`.
Use this link in your `forEach` loop

```
<a href="/posts/report/<%= post._id %>" >Report Post</a>
```

And here is your route.

```
router.get('/posts/report/:id',(req,res) => {
    Post.findById(req.params.id, (err,post) => {
        if(err){
            // handle error here
        }else{  
            // Here you can do what you want.
            // You can update post object.
            post.reported = true;
            post.save((error, updatedPost) => {
               // run code here.
               // You can redirect to the previous page with all posts
               // or do anything else you want.
            });      
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: i render all of the posts as posts and then go through them with a foreach, every post get a report option, so i can i render the correct post?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do. What does `report` do? Give some extra info.

Comment: i have user model and post model, in the post as i wrote there is a reported that default set to false, if the link is clicked, the reported for the post will turn into true, and the post will be shown in a page for admins that shows reported posts. all is set but the report button

Comment: So by clicking each button you want to update the `post.reported` property in mongodb. If i understand well, by clicking the button you have to make a post request to change that value